# How to customize sidebar VSCode colors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I'm modifying the sidebar explorer colors to #f7f6f2.

But some of the items aren't updating. Any idea how to target these remaining items?

[image: VSCode Sidebar]

Added this to the settings.json

```json
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "sideBar.foreground": "#f7f6f2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```json
 "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#f7f6f2"
```

To find these kind of things you can use developer tools (cmd + shift + p, "toggle developer tools")

PS: there are other keys too that you might wanna configure:

[image]